# Usage of Custom Transparency band for elevation raster in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity, band

I would like to set a raster transparency to represent its elevation, so that the mountain tops are opaque and gradually become transparent toward their foot.

On the `Layer Properties > Transparency` tab, in `Custom Transparency Options`, I found **Transparency band** and would like to use it.

[image]

Problem is, I do not know how to control the transparency according to the band I have just assigned (`Band1` in the above image).

At default setting it gives me an uncomfortable image (right-hand-side; below).

[image]

I also tried simple color ramp such as Reds, but the output is still weird.

[image]

**Q**uestion: How can I use this **Transparency band** function ?

Alternatively, giving a list of transparent pixel seems to work. But I have to give a color range in stepwise manner, and it is far from gradual change I hope to achieve.

[image]

Note: I borrowed the West Timor elevation data from [SAGA GIS Tutorials](https://sagatutorials.wordpress.com/) - [Downloads](https://sagatutorials.wordpress.com/downloads/).

Comment: mh I don't think that's what you want; the band-wide transparency is meant for single pixel color transparency, specified by exact RGB values. I'd rather go for the *Singleband pseudocolor* rendering, create a color ramp with a few colors and assign opacity to each color individually? the opacity will be interpolated over the ramp.

Comment: Thanks so much @ThingumaBob ! I am still reluctant to give up on this Transparency band trick (if any), but your suggested color ramp technique definitely gave me what I wanted.

Comment: @ThingumaBob please, will you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept as solution?